# Controller for Autonomous Mining Vehicle

Tags: graphics-cards

What is a good CUDA enabled controller for an autonomous mining vehicle?

It needs to be vibration resistant, atleast IP67, have 4 CAN ports, and 1 ethernet port.

I am using python / ROS for vision, sensor fusion, SLAM etc.

Comment: Is it safe for posters to assume you have no price limit?

Comment: Preferably below $5000.